# Does the structure group of S^n homotopic to O(n+1)?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles

It is easy to show that Diff(S^1) is homotopic to O(2), but in the case of n bigger than 1 things become really complicated, I cannot see the conclusion directly.

Comment: More precisely, I think, you are asking if the subgroup $O(n+1)< Diff(S^n)$ is a deformation retract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The proof for $S^2$ is in [lecture notes by Lurie](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/937notes/937Lecture24.pdf).
- The proof for $S^3$ is [due to Hatcher](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/SmaleConjecture.pdf) [added by studiosus].
- [What is the homotopy type of the group of diffeomorphisms of the 4-sphere?](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/?q=op/what_is_the_homotopy_type_of_the_group_of_diffeomorphisms_of_the_4_sphere) is a problem in the Open Problem Garden.

Comment: In addition, for $n=3$ this is Hatcher's theorem: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/SmaleConjecture.pdf

Comment: @studiosus Thanks; I added this to the post and marked it CW.